# How are bulk cut structures obtained?

Tags: structure, nanostructures, nanoparticles

I am studying nanoclusters in which I have searched the DFT energy landscape and data mining was performed. As the next step, I am trying to prepare a few bulk cut structures but I have no experience in it.

What is the general method for obtaining the bulk cut structures?

Do you obtain the structures by leaving a structure with correct stoichiometry and removing the rest of the atoms?

Comment: As a starting point, a great free software tool for preparing cut crystals is VESTA.

Comment: @HaydenS I'm using VESTA but I was not aware of that! Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: @HaydenS It sounds like you know a bit about the subject! Do you think you can help answer the question? It would be nice since our unanswered queue is now at 318 questions!!!

Comment: @DGKang Did you figure out the answer yet?

Comment: @DGKang any update?